# How can I use a stored procedure in Linq-to-SQL and asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure that forbid from duplicate email address .

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckEmail1]
(@email nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN            
   DECLARE @ERORR NVARCHAR(50)
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   if not exists (SELECT C.Email FROM Customer C WHERE Email=@email)
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Customer (Email) VALUES (@email) 
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
      declare @errormessage nvarchar(50) = 'This Email Address is Exists'
      RAISERROR (@errormessage,11,1)
   END
END
```

I want to use this stored procedure in asp.net textbox ? How can I do that?
and this is my C# Code :

```
try
{
   var db = new DataClassesDataContext();
   db.CheckEmail1(TextBox1.Text);
   db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Label6.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: what's your problem ?

Comment: hope this link helpful to you http://www.ezineasp.net/post/LINQ-to-SQL-Insert-Operation-by-Stored-Procedure-using-C-sharp.aspx

Comment: my problem is i cant insert in sql with up procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call db.SubmitChanges(); It's required with modified LINQ to SQL objects only.

Comment: excuse me would you explain more and give me sample please?

Comment: Your code is correct and should work as expected (but you don't need db.SubmitChanges()). I just tested it myself and I get inserted one email on a first run and then get an error on second run. Check if TextBox1.Text has a value and if Label6 is visible.